# Django templates won't load but HttpResponse will (repost)

Tags: python, django

I recently began learning django and have been running into some trouble and I can't figure out why.

My problem is quite simple: whenever I try to run my homepage with a template, it throws up a 404 error.

My file hierarchy is as such:

```
crm
 accounts
  templates
   accounts
    dashboard.html
  urls.py
  views.py
 crm
  urls.py
```

In crm/urls, I have

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls'))
```

Then in accounts/urls, there is,

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

And in views, I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
```

My dashboard.html is just a basic html file with a title and h1, that's it.

Also, whenever I change

```
return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

to

```
return HttpResponse('home')
```

in my home function, it decides to show. 
I have tried recreating the project, uninstalling and reinstalling django, renaming a few things, but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Do you set `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must let Django know you have a new application and set its name in `crm/settings.py`

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'accounts', # --> name your app
    ]
```

Comment: `HttpResponse` is working successfully so, problem is not with the app but the problem is on `template loading`.